# Would a GUT-monopole powered rocket be feasible?

Tags: space, travel

Would a rocket or Bussard ramjet powered by monopole induced proton decay (Callan-Rubakov mechanism) be a feasible method for near-light interstellar flight? There are such drives in the Orion's Arm worldbuilding project (conversion drives) and in some of Alistair Reynolds's stories, but there seems to be little other interest in them.

This assumes the existence of GUT monopoles, of course.

Comment: Maybe I am out of the niche really into the topic, but it would help if you could give some details about what you propose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is a sufficiently mechanism for a Bussard ramjet propulsion. Assuming the efficiencies of conversion of hydrogen are capable of reasonable rate of acceleration. In fact, the timescales determined by acceleration to reach near-lightspeed may be a drawback.

Discussing conversion drives on Orion's Arm they suggest for beam core rocket engines that: --

> The equivalent of antimatter beam core, this rocket engine is intended to induce baryon decay in the entirety of the reaction mass. This is a difficult proposition even for second singularity minds, as it either requires very long reaction chambers to ensure than all baryons react with a monopole (which has serious heat rejection, shielding and mass requirements) or a very high monopole density in the reaction chamber. This in turn has its own problems, as like-charged monopoles will repel limiting the density and opposite-charged monopoles will attract forming neutral monopolium bound states that will shoot out of the reaction chamber without contributing much more useful work.

While for Bussard ramjets using conversion drive propulsion systems: --

> The use of conversion monopoles in a ramjet starship is where the design really shows its advantages. Basic engine power and thrust are equivalent to antimatter fuelled Ram-Augmented Interstellar Rockets, but the ability to recycle the monopoles vastly increases efficiency. Much longer journeys can be undertaken before the monopole fuel reserves are exhausted.

However, they indicate that: --

> Specific impulse is no higher than 10,000,000 seconds

This suggests that velocity upper bound is equivalent to a large fraction of lightspeed, but not necessarily near-lightspeed itself. At a guess this looks like around one-third of lightspeed. A reasonable velocity for interstellar travel, but not good for large amounts of relativistic time dilation, so biosuspension will be necessary to while away the long years trundling between the stars.

Comment: Thank you! Just out of question, how did you get the one-third of c figure? Orion's Arm lists the max velocity for a conversion ramjet at .96c: https://orionsarm.com/eg-article/49f6ffc730720

Comment: @AskerOfQuestions I'm glad you asked. It was a guess, which I tried to make clear in my answer, therefore, likely to be wrong, but I was prepared to stick my neck out. It was an extrapolation from the value of specific impulse. I recommend going with Oriion's Arm figures. At a maximum velocity of 0.96 c, the time dilation is only 3.57 (based on an online relativity calculator). Travel for 357 years at 0.96 c, & shiptime is 100 years. At a cruising velocity of 0.84 c, time dilation is 1.843. With a range of 10,00 light years plus biosuspension will be needed.

Comment: North/south monopoles attract each other and annihilate. Same pole monopoles create ridiculously big repulsion force in any noticable amount.

Comment: @Vashu Good point! Best to assume that problem has been solved. Provided north & south monopoles are contained in a structure that keeps them separated, but still able to convert protons it might work. Definitely a non-trivial exercise in engineering. Also, monopolar repulsion might have interesting technological applications. I appreciate your comment.